# Functor from Order Category to Top Category

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let **Order** be the category whose objects are totally ordered sets and whose morphisms are monotone functions, and let **Top** be the category whose objects are topological spaces and whose morphism are continuous functions.

Then given an ordered sets $A$ with relation $\leq_A$, we can construct a topology $\mathcal{T}_{\leq_A}$ on $A$ with a basis consisting of the following types of sets:

$$(a,b) = \{x|a<_A x <_A b\},$$
$$ (-\infty,b) = \{x|x <_A b\},$$
$$ (a,\infty) = \{x|a<_A x\}.$$

where $a<_A b$ means $a\leq_A b$ but $a\neq b$. I am supposed to show that there is a functor $F:$ **Order**$ \to$ **Top** that maps $(A,\leq_A)$ to $(A,\mathcal{T}_{\leq_A})$ and takes a monotone function $f:A\to B$ to the same function.

Now in order for this actually to be a functor, it must hold that the monotone functions $f:A\to B$ are continuous functions in order for them to be morphisms in **Top**, but I don't see why this must necessarily be true.

For instance, $\Bbb{R}$ is an ordered set. So let us say that $A=B=\Bbb{R}$. Then the topology induced by the order is just the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$. Then consider the floor function $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$. This is not a continuous function because $f^{-1}(0.5,1.5) = [1,2)$ which is not an open set in this topology.

So it seems to me that the above is a counterexample to the claim that a monotone function between two ordered sets is necessarily continuous in the topology induced by that order. Is this the case? If this is not a counterexample, I don't see how to prove that the monotone functions are continuous.

Comment: Why is the floor function monotone?

Comment: Because whenever $a\leq b$, this implies $\lfloor a \rfloor \leq \lfloor b \rfloor$.

Comment: But $\lfloor 0 \rfloor = \lfloor 0.5 \rfloor$. Oh wait, I see what you're saying now.

Comment: What is the author's definition of monotone?  Strictly so?

Comment: The definition of monotone in this case is that $a\leq_A a'$ implies $f(a) \leq_B f(a')$, where $\leq_A$ and $\leq_B$ are the order relations on the respective sets.  So no, not strictly so.

Comment: Then I agree with you.  I don't buy it at all.

Comment: Where is this exercise from?

Comment: It's from an assignment that I assume my professor wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right--monotone functions are not continuous in general.  If you want to get a functor of the sort you're looking for, you'll need to severely restrict the maps you allow in $\mathbf{Order}$.  For instance, it would suffice to consider maps which preserve suprema and infima of arbitrary subsets.

Comment: Is there some non-obvious trick in order to prove that "maps which preserve suprema and infima of arbitrary subsets" are continuous? I tried to prove it by myself and, after failing repeatedly, I found a proof in Schechter's HAF (but it is quite puzzling). Anyway, I can ask it as a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: Well, if you have an order-preserving map $f:A\to B$ and an open interval $I\subseteq B$ which contains $f(a)$, then the only way $f^{-1}(I)$ can fail to contain an interval of the form $(b,a]$ is if $a$ is the least element of $f^{-1}(I)$ and $a$ has no predecessor.  But then you can use the fact that $a$ is the supremum of $\{x\in A:x<a\}$ and the fact that $f$ preserves suprema to get a contradiction.  So $f^{-1}(I)$ contains an interval $(b,a]$, and similarly it contains an interval $[a,c)$, so it is a neighborhood of $a$.